# PhpStorm doesn't resolve method of parent class in children class

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

PhpStorm is not able to resolve the method of a parent class inside of child class. The method is definitely part of the parent class. Every class on this code basis has this problem.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: As AH.Pooladvand stated, you need Laravel IDE Helper package -- it will generate additional files for IDE use that will help it understand the **Laravel magic methods** (calling non existing static `where` method and the way how Laravel makes it to actually work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case which is laravel related problem you can use [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) 
after installation checkout the [usage](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#usage)
and also there is a phpstorm plugin named laravel
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel